# Returning a column C value list based on context of column A & B

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, offset

I want to make a contextual drop down menu based on 2 other conditions.

All of my data are in the same table, 3 columns.

[image: see picture here]

The list of results needs to be dependent of the column A first (yellow), and then B (blue), which will list all the results the results in column C (green). I can't seem to be able to do that on the 3rd level (column c in green) and I need help with that.

[image]

My Excel is in French so I'll use OFFSET (DECALER) and MATCH (EQUIV) function and the `COUNTIFS (NB.SI.ENS)` to determine length of the list.

```
=DECALER(TAB_NOM_DEMO[[#En-têtes];[SUCCURSALE]];EQUIV(TABLEAU_ACC_SUCC[@SUCCURSALE];TAB_NOM_DEMO[SUCCURSALE];0);
  EQUIV(TABLEAU_ACC_SUCC[[#En-têtes];[TYPE DEMO]];TAB_NOM_DEMO[#En-têtes];0);NB.SI.ENS(TAB_NOM_DEMO[SUCCURSALE];
  TABLEAU_ACC_SUCC[@SUCCURSALE];TAB_NOM_DEMO[TYPE DEMO];TABLEAU_ACC_SUCC[@[TYPE DEMO]]);1)
```

My problem that I see right now is that the start cell:

```
TAB_NOM_DEMO[[#En-têtes];[SUCCURSALE]]
```

needs to be variable of column A first, then column B to get the right data in column C.

I'm not sure I'm using the right function right now so I'm open to suggestions.

### Update

I had great results with the FILTER function so far. It works well in a test cell, I only the results I need to see. But I can't make it happen in data validation list... why?

```
=TRIER(FILTRE(TAB_NOM_DEMO[NOM DEMO];
 (TAB_NOM_DEMO[SUCCURSALE]=TABLEAU_ACC_SUCC[@SUCCURSALE])*
 (TAB_NOM_DEMO[TYPE DEMO]=TABLEAU_ACC_SUCC[@[TYPE DEMO]])))
```

Comment: So I would replace offset() with index() - I find it more stable and easier to control.

Comment: Never use offset. Volatile formula. Always a better way. Index, named range, etc. And dangit... now I'm hungry for french fries!

Comment: ok so instead of OFFSET i managed to have the desired results with FILTER function but can't have it result in a dropdown list

Comment: You can use your FILTER solution in a cell somewhere and reference to that cell. For instance `D1` has the filter-formula, than refer to `D1#`

Comment: This filter formula works well with the first row only. Doesn't changes for the other rows since the cell contains the formula  =FILTRE(TAB_NOM_DEMO[NOM DEMO];(TAB_NOM_DEMO[SUCCURSALE]=TABLEAU_ACC_SUCC[@SUCCURSALE])*(TAB_NOM_DEMO[TYPE DEMO]=TABLEAU_ACC_SUCC[@[TYPE DEMO]]))

what should i do to correct that so it changes for all of the rows?